# Selenium Cucumber Repository (Java) Picocontainer issue

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, webdriver-manager

Hi everybody: I'm creating a repository in Maven with Cucumber, Selenium, TestNG.

What I'm trying to do is getting the values from a properties file for sending these parameters with Selenium, but I cannot reach with the solution to the issues generated here.

This is the structure of my project:

```
    .
├── pom.xml
├── selenium_cucumber.iml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── utilities
│   │   │       ├── LoadProperties.java
│   │   │       └── ReportMerger.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── config.properties
│   │       └── log4j.properties
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   ├── features
│       │   │   └── first.feature
│       │   ├── hooks
│       │   │   ├── ServiceHooks.java
│       │   │   ├── TakesScreenshots.java
│       │   │   └── WebDriverManager.java
│       │   ├── pages
│       │   │   ├── BasePage.java
│       │   │   └── Page_First.java
│       │   ├── runners
│       │   │   └── testNGCucumberRunner.java
│       │   └── steps
│       │       └── Step_First.java
│       └── resources
│           └── testng.xml
└── target
```

This is my feature file:

```
@test
Feature: Navigation Test
  This is example of using Cucumber-JVM with TestNG and Selenium


  Scenario: Search google.com to verify google search is working

    Given I go to "<Url>" Google
    When I query for "<search>" cucumber spring selenium
    And click search
    Then google page title should become the first page
```

Continue with the page that load the properties from a properties file (**config.properties**)

```
package utilities;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;


public class LoadProperties {

    Properties prop;

    public LoadProperties(){

        try{
            prop = new Properties();

            File fis = new File("src/main/resources/config.properties");

            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fis);

            prop.load(input);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error loading configuration file");
        }
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return prop.getProperty("Url");
    }

    public String getNavigator(){

        return prop.getProperty("navigator");
    }

    public String searchData(){

        return prop.getProperty("search");
    }

}
```

The **config.properties** file:

```
navigator = "firefox"
Url = "https://www.google.com"
search = "cucumber spring selenium"
```

Very important to mention that I'm using the API **WebdriverManager** (By Boni Garcia), because with this it is not necessary put the drivers of each browser in a folder and download them.

```
package hooks;

import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

    @Component
    public class WebDriverManager {

        private WebDriver webDriver;


        public WebDriver getDriver() {
            return webDriver;
        }

        @Bean(destroyMethod = "quit")
        public WebDriver getWebDriver(){
            String currentWebDriver = System.getProperty("browser", "");
            switch(currentWebDriver) {
                case ("chrome"):
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
                    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
                case ("firefox"):
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
                    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                    firefoxOptions.setCapability("marionette", true);
                    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
                    break;
                case ("chromeHeadless"):
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
                    ChromeOptions chromeHeadless = new ChromeOptions();
                    chromeHeadless.setHeadless(true);
                    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeHeadless);
                    break;
                case ("iexplorer"):
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilitiesIE = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                    capabilitiesIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
                    webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilitiesIE);
                    break;
                case ("edge"):
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
                    webDriver = new EdgeDriver();
                    break;
                case ("opera"):
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "operadriver.exe");
                    webDriver = new OperaDriver();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.getProperty("browser", "chrome");
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
                    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
            }

            //Using Selenide driver:
            WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(webDriver);
            return webDriver;
        }

        @PreDestroy
        public void closeSession(){
            getDriver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
            getDriver().close();
            getDriver().quit();
        }
}
```

By other hand I'm working with **Page Factory**, this is the Common Base Page for working with:

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public abstract class BasePage {

    private WebDriver driver ;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BasePage.class.getName());

    //Constructor
    public BasePage(WebDriver driver){

        this.driver = driver;
        this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        this.driver.getTitle();

        log.info("______________________Starting tests______________________");
    }

    public String getPageTitle(){
        return driver.getTitle();
    }

    public Logger getLOG() {
        return log;
    }


    public void navigate(String Url){
        driver.get(Url);
    }

/*
    public abstract boolean isAt();
*/

    //Methods

    protected void waitForElementClickable(WebElement element){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    }

    protected void waitForElementVisible(WebElement element){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    }

    protected void setTextAs(WebElement element, String text) throws IOException {
        waitForElementClickable(element);
        element.sendKeys((text));
    }

    protected void clearElement(WebElement element){
        waitForElementClickable(element);
        element.clear();
    }

    protected void clickElement(WebElement element){
        waitForElementClickable(element);
        element.click();
    }

    protected void clickElementByJavascriptExecutor(String xpath){
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        JavascriptExecutor ex=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        ex.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
    }

    protected void clickLink(WebElement element){
        waitForElementVisible(element);
        element.click();
    }

    protected String getText(WebElement element){
        waitForElementVisible(element);
        return element.getText();
    }


    protected void freeze(int seconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't we forget about a Test Runner Class (**testNGCucumberRunner**)

```
package runners;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.PickleEventWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty","json:target/report/cucumber2.json", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
        strict = true,
        features = {"src/test/java/features"},
        tags = {"@test"},
        glue = {"steps"}
)
    public class testNGCucumberRunner {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(runners.testNGCucumberRunner.class);
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "Cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleEventWrapper pickleEvent, CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        LOG.info("STARTING THIS FEATURE >>>>>" + cucumberFeature + "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickleEvent());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

Also the Hooks class is present here (**ServiceHooks**)

```
package hooks;

import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import static com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver;

public class ServiceHooks {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceHooks.class);
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Before
    public void setUpBrowser(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {

        log.info("****************************************************************************************");
        log.info("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Start of execution of scenario with name: " + scenario.getName() + "    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        log.info("****************************************************************************************");

        if (webDriver == null) {
            log.error("WebDriver did not initialize correctly");
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = getWebDriver();
        log.info("****************************************************************************************");
        log.info("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Completion of execution of scenario with name: " + scenario.getName() + "    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        log.info("****************************************************************************************");
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            log.info("****************************************************************************************");
            log.info("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Failing scenario with name: " + scenario.getName() + "    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
            log.info("****************************************************************************************");
            try {
                byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
            } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
                System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
            }
        }
        driver.quit();
        log.info("Driver closed");
    }
}
```

My POM cannot be forgotten here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium_cucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <cucumber.version>3.0.2</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>3.12.0</selenium.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/selenide -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My testng.xml file is the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Google Suite" verbose="1" thread-count="1" parallel="tests" configfailurepolicy="continue">
    <test name="Google UI automation">
        <classes>
            <class name="runners.testNGCucumberRunner">
                <methods>
                    <include name="scenario"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The Page related with the feature named before is the next:

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Page_First extends BasePage{

    /////////////Constructor/////////////

    public Page_First(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////WEB ELEMENTS//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @FindBy(name = "q")
    private WebElement searchText;

    @FindBy(name="btnK")
    private WebElement searchButton;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////BASE METHODS//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void search(String search) throws IOException {
        setTextAs(searchText, search);
    }

    public void enterButton (){
        clickElement(searchButton);
    }
}
```

And the step definitions class related with this is the next one:

```
package steps;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import pages.BasePage;
import pages.Page_First;
import utilities.LoadProperties;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Step_First {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private BasePage basepage;


    private Page_First page_first = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Page_First.class);


    private static final java.util.logging.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Page_First.class.getName());
    LoadProperties load = new LoadProperties();


    public Step_First(WebDriver driver){

        this.driver = driver;
    }


    @Given("I go to {string} Google")
    public void I_go_to_Google (String Url) {

        load.getUrl();
    //    basepage.navigate(Url);
    }

    @When("I query for {string} cucumber spring selenium")
    public void I_query_for_cucumber_spring_selenium (String search) throws IOException {

        page_first.search(search);
    }

    @When("click search")
    public void click_search(){

        page_first.enterButton();
    }

    @Then("google page title should become the first page")
    public void google_page_title_should_become_the_first_page() {

        log.info("All OK");

    }
}
```

After all this information and classes and more classes, I really don't know where I'm failing, because when I run the **testNGCucumberRunner** class from the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) I'm getting the next error in console:

```
    @test
  Scenario: Search google.com to verify google search is working # src/test/java/features/first.feature:6
    Given I go to "<Url>" Google                                 # Step_First.I_go_to_Google(String)
      org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: steps.Step_First has unsatisfied dependency 'interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver' for constructor 'public steps.Step_First(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@4c12331b:1<|
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:191)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.access$100(ConstructorInjector.java:51)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:331)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:55)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:42)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:53)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:47)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:44)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:56)
    at runners.testNGCucumberRunner.scenario(testNGCucumberRunner.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    ...
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
    at ✽.I go to "<Url>" Google (src/test/java/features/first.feature:8)
```

I think is something related with **picocontainer** dependency (Included in my POM), but I cannot reach the failing issue.

```
Failed scenarios:
src/test/java/features/first.feature:6 # Search google.com to verify google search is working

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
4 Steps (1 failed, 3 skipped)
0m0.071s

org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: steps.Step_First has unsatisfied dependency 'interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver' for constructor 'public steps.Step_First(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@4c12331b:1<|
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:191)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.access$100(ConstructorInjector.java:51)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:331)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50)
    ...
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:56)
    at runners.testNGCucumberRunner.scenario(testNGCucumberRunner.java:33)
    ...
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
    at ✽.I go to "<Url>" Google (src/test/java/features/first.feature:8)



===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

May anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to read the exception message carefully. The exception is not related to pico container. But rather pico container is telling you about a problem with your step definitions.

```
org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException:
steps.Step_First has unsatisfied dependency 'interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver'
for constructor 'public steps.Step_First(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver)'
from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@4c12331b:1<|
```

So there is something wrong the constructor for `First_Step`. It has an unsatisfied dependency. This means that pico container can't figure out how to create an instance of it `First_Step` .

```
    public Step_First(WebDriver driver){

        this.driver = driver;
    }
```

If you look at the constructor you can see that it declares a dependency on `WebDriver`. So you must have an instance of the `WebDriver` before you can create `Step_First`.
Normally pico container would try to create a web driver for you. But because `WebDriver` is an interface it can't create an instance of it.

So you may instead want to inject `ServiceHooks` instead because inside that class you are creating an instance of `WebDriver`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above answer. As a better solution, use a 'Test Context' class to store all required objects while swapping multiple step classes.

Test Context class can store:

- WebDriver object,
- page objects,
- DataReader object, etc.

Use a pageobject manager to keep page classes. Below is a code segment in the pageobject manager class.

```
private HomePage;  
public HomePage getHomePage(){
      return (homePage == null) ? homePage = new HomePage(driver) : homePage;
      }
```

Please refer to this too.
https://cucumber.io/blog/bdd/polymorphic-step-definitions/